# Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I started learning AngularJS but had a little problem....
What is wrong here ? I try to declare songlist as an array with Song Objects but get an error to use "="

```
import { Song } from './song.model';

export class Chart
{
  id:number;
  chartName: string;
  img: string;
  createDate:string;

  songList[]: Song;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declartion is invalid, should be:

`songList: Song[]`

Answer (score 2):

Check out this typescript type definition for arrays.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

The syntax for typescript typecasting is

```
variable: type;
```

So for an array you'll want something like

```
songList: Array<Song>;
```

or

```
songList: Song[];
```